# What are these bluish/greenish edges in edit mode?

Tags: interface

I created a 3d human face with 'Facegen Modeller' and I opened it with Blender, trying to adapt it to my needs. Inside the eye there is a bluish/greenish oval shape. What is that? When I try to mark it as seam, the color does not change. I removed that shape in edit mode and then created it again and now it seems to be marked correctly. Am I making a mistake?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You marked those edges as being sharp, possibly by accident.

It happens when you select an edge or edgeloop and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> > *Mark Sharp*

To remove it select the edge or edgeloop in question and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> > *Clear Sharp*

Comment: Or they could have been marked sharp by the other application. Good answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah could have happened by accident, or by mistakenly pressing some key combination or by some addon or tool.

Comment: what's sharp,in a few words ?

Comment: Sharp edges are used on smooth shaded meshes to create a break on an otherwise continuous surface, think a corner or sharp edge in the surface